# Does Brilliant keep the courses done after Premium?

Tags: brilliant

I have purchased Brilliant app, and I've been wondering if anyone could answer me if after the month that I've paid for Premium, if I cancel my subscription for the next month, does the progress I've done on some courses stay? Like are those courses I've done while I had the premium subscription stay available to redo after subscription if I want to?

Comment: Have you tried asking them ?